# Diferencia entre asignar variables por valor o referencia

Tags: c

He visto varios trozos de código en c donde al asignar un valor a una variable no usan el '&' y he leído que es algo sobre valor o referencia, alguien me podría explicar?

```
char userName[25];   
printf("Ingresa tu nombre de usuario: \n");
scanf("%s", userName);
```

o también usan el

```
int num;
printf("Ingresa un numero: \n");
scanf("%d",&num);
```

Comment: Donde está el paso por referencia en el código que mencionas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al pasar una variable a una funcion mediante valor, lo que se hace es pasar **una copia** de la informacion contenida en esa variable, por lo que tendremos **dos instancias diferentes** de la misma variable; una que esta en el medio en el que se envió y otra que esta en el medio donde fue enviada. Asi si se modifica la informacion de la variable enviada esta solo sera cambiada en ese ambiente.

Al pasar una variable a una funcion por referencia lo que hacemos en realidad es pasar un apuntador **a la direccion en memoria** en la que se localiza la variable en si, por lo que al modicar la informacion mediante el apuntador en el metodo al que fue enviada esta sera modificada en todos los ambitos ya que en realidad modificamos la variable original, de hecho la única ya que mediante esta forma no se hace otra copia de la variable.

por ejemplo

```
//declaro funciones
int sumarXvalor(int a,int b);
void sumarXreferencia(int a,int b,int *resultado);

int main( ) {
 int a = 0;
 int b = 0;
 int resultado = 0;

 //por valor 
 printf( "paso de valor por valor" );
 resultado = sumaXvalor( a, b );

 // por referencia
 printf( "Paso de Parametros por ReferencianPasamos el valor de posicion en memoria de la variable resultado: %pn", &resultado );
 sumarXreferencia( a, b, &resultado );
 printf( "Resultado: %in", resultado );
 return 0;
}

int sumarXvalor( int a, int b ) {
 return a+b;
}

void sumarXreferencia( int a, int b, int *resultado ) {
 *resultado = a + b;
}
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda, hace mucho tiempo no toco C, perdon si hay algun error saludos.